# Some keys not working after booting Linux

Tags: linux

Sometimes when I boot Linux (any distro), <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> keys on my laptop keyboard don't work. Booting into any Linux liveCD doesn't fix the issue, but booting into Windows installer does.  It happens randomly, no crushes, normal shutdown, no errors while booting.

My laptop is HP Pavilion Gaming 15.

Comment: *HP Pavilion Gaming 15* is meaningless, there are dozens of different models. If this is happening with the integrated keyboard (vs an USB one) then specific model number matters. Also the distros you've been trying and show the problem and kernel versions (I suspect something on the 6.x branch).